# Azure Load Balancer Session Persistence

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am unable to find a way to set the Azure Network LB session persistence via the CLI. I am able to do this in the Azure portal by adding a "load balancing rule", but can't find this option in the CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting session persistence can be done with the `--load-distribution` argument [per the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/lb/rule#create).